# Find alphabetically first value using PHP

Tags: php, sorting, usort, alphabetical-sort, natsort

I am writing a sort function (using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)), and part of the operation I want to do there is determining which value comes first alphabetically. (This is only part of the operation, hence I'm not using [natsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).) This means I have two strings for which I need to determine which is alphabetically first. Since this operation gets done in a loop, I want to have this done as simple as possible. One thing I could do is construct an array out of the two elements and use natsort on that. Is there a better approach, that does not involve constructing an array from the two values?

Edit: `$a > $b` seems to get basic cases right, though I'm not sure of how correct this behaves.

Comment: Please be more specific. An example of exactly what you want would be nice.

Comment: $a > $b will fail for cases like $a = '05' and $b = '005', because then, to PHP, $a == $b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp) for that:

From the documentation:

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Code:

```
$str1 = 'foo';
$str2 = 'bar';

if(strcmp($str1, $str2) < 0) {
  echo '$str1 comes first';
} elseif(strcmp($str1, $str2) > 0 ){
  echo '$str2 comes first';
}
```

Output:

```
$str2 comes first
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/J98D8Mj0)

Comment: This is wrong. It will only enter in the else block if both strings are identical. In that case, strcmp returns 0. If $str1 comes first, it will return 1, and -1 if $str2 comes first.

Comment: @Portnoy: Please re-check the answer. I corrected it before :)